# Graphite time ranges > 48 hours not working

Tags: grafana, graphite

Currently running `grafana v5.0.4` with `graphite 0.9.13` both on AWS. Our infrastructure is on AWS and highly dynamic. Instances are spun up and down very often which I believe is causing graphs to break when you try to go back over 24 hours. From testing, I believe because we use wildcards in our graph configuration, it looks up both running and nonrunning instances.

We cant delete instance information of nonrunning instances because they are needed for historical purposes. Has someone experienced this issue or have any workaround?

On the 24-hour chart you see data plotted for 4 items: `batch, nlp, web, jboss, batch2`, pickup while on the past 7 days chart that includes the same period, you only see the data plotted for `web, jboss and batch2`.

The data for the other types (`batch, nlp`) are not rendering.

I speculate that this might be because batch and nlp hosts have been destroyed and redeployed during this 7-day period, while the others were not. I have attached graphite screenshoots. As you can see graph works well for 4 actual running instances and once a 5th nonrunning instance is introduced, graph breaks.

**Update removed grafana pictures to add graphite because I can only post 2 pictures:**

Working

[image]

Not Working once nonrunning instance added

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your data has been lost in between time ranges.This function might help you.It can cater null values. Try this

**interpolate(seriesList)**

Takes one metric or a wildcard seriesList, and optionally a limit to the number of ‘None’ values to skip over. Continues the line with the last received value when gaps (‘None’ values) appear in your data, rather than breaking your line.

Example:

&target=interpolate(Server01.connections.handled)